# Force encryption flag doesn't save

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to set the server to force encryption when I hit apply the message saying that it will take affect after restarting pops up, but when I open the box again its back to NO as nothing was.

Also my self signed trusted certificate is not in the list. I'm not sure if thats the same issue or not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I don't have the rights to write to the registry that causes the issue.

(It would be nice if sql would throw an error not just close the box without saving).

I found the registry key to edit here:
http://kushagrarakesh.blogspot.com/2011_10_01_archive.html